# In maven, how can I execute a SQL if I detect the table structure is missing?

Tags: maven-2, automated-tests, executequery

I'm modifying an existing maven2 project and I would like to create the database structure if I notice it is missing.

I sort-of know how to do this in ant, I could query the database and if the table is missing I could execute the query.

But, maven is a different thing. I found a [SQL plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/sql-maven-plugin/execute-mojo.html) to run the script, but I don't know where or how to detect if the database structure is missing? Also where in the "goals" should I check for this?..

I would put this on the test.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

I would use a database migration tool for this, something like the [dbmaintain-maven-plugin](http://source.mysema.com/display/maven/Maven+Plugins) or Carbon Five [db-migration-maven-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/c5-db-migration).

Comment: Looks nice, I'll take a look at it.